# React: работа с хуками

Tags: reactjs

Я вывожу список элементов массива на страницу. Я хочу по клику на кнопку hide список прятался, но кнопка не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

 function App () {
let [state, setState] = useState({

isHeaderVisible: true,
todos: [
{id: 0, title: 'title 0', content: 'First Content'},
{id: 1, title: 'title 1', content: 'Second Content'},
{id: 2, title: 'title 2', content: 'Third Content'}]
})

let HideList = () => {
setState({
...state,
isHeaderVisible: !state.isHeaderVisible
})
}

return (
<div>
{state.todos.map(todo => (
<div>{todo.id} , {todo.title} , {todo.content}</div>
)))}
<button onClick={HideList}>Hide</button>
</div>
)
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `setState({
...state,
isHeaderVisible: !state.isHeaderVisible
})` так не делают. делают так: `setState(p=> ({ ...p, isHeaderVisible: !p.isHeaderVisible }))`

Comment: ну и собсно у вас нет условия, чтобы список прятался.

Comment: @entithat Большое тебе спасибо) Очень трудно учиться просто и нужно была помощь

Comment: @entithat уже понял))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы спрятать список надо так же добавить условие, т.е. проверять `state.isHeaderVisible` `true` или `false`.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isHeaderVisible: true,
    todos: [
      { id: 0, title: "title 0", content: "First Content" },
      { id: 1, title: "title 1", content: "Second Content" },
      { id: 2, title: "title 2", content: "Third Content" }
    ]
  });

  function hideList() {
    setState((p) => ({
      ...p,
      isHeaderVisible: !p.isHeaderVisible
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {state.isHeaderVisible &&
        state.todos.map((todo) => (
          <div>
            {todo.id} , {todo.title} , {todo.content}
          </div>
        ))}
      <button onClick={() => hideList()}>Hide</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```